# My cookie value is getting overwritten before being read when saving user preferences

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies

I have a table that is sortable by clicking on the column headings.  By default, it sorts by the months remaining column in ascending order.  However, if the user sorts by title, I wanted it to remember this so when they came back to the page, it was still sorted by title so I have added the tableSort cookie to remember this value.

My issue is saving the sorting order.

The title is working so when a user returns to the page, it is now sorted by the column they chose but always in ascending order.  I have tried setting the order in tableSortDirection which does save asc or desc but now, on page load, the title is clicked from the value in tableSort which then changes the value in tableSortDirection to asc before it's been read so it never sorts in desc.

Any suggestions please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

    const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) =>
        v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
        )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

    // do the work...
    document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const table = th.closest('table');
        const columnIndex = Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th);
        const isAscending = this.asc = !this.asc;
        Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
            .sort(comparer(columnIndex, isAscending))
            .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr));    
        document.cookie = `tableSortColumn=${th.dataset.sort}; path=/`;
        document.cookie = `tableSortDirection=${isAscending ? 'asc' : 'desc'}; path=/`;
    }));

    // read the user's sorting preference from cookie, or default to 'months_remaining' descending
    const sortColumnCookie = document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('tableSortColumn='));
    const sortDirectionCookie = document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('tableSortDirection='));

    const defaultSortColumn = 'months_remaining';
    const defaultSortDirection = false; // descending
    let sortedColumn = defaultSortColumn;
    let sortDirection = defaultSortDirection;
    if (sortColumnCookie) {
        sortedColumn = sortColumnCookie.split('=')[1];
    }
    if (sortDirectionCookie) {
        sortDirection = sortDirectionCookie.split('=')[1] === 'asc';
    }
    // sort the table using the user's preference
    const sortHeader = document.querySelector(`th[data-sort="${sortedColumn}"]`);
    if (sortHeader) {
        if (sortDirection) {
            sortHeader.click();
            sortHeader.click();
        } else {
            sortHeader.click();
        }
    } else {
        // fallback to default sort column and direction
        document.querySelector('.months_remaining').click();
    }

    // set the direction cookie to the last used direction
    const currentSortDirectionCookie = document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('tableSortDirection='));
    if (currentSortDirectionCookie) {
        document.cookie = `${currentSortDirectionCookie}; path=/`;
    }
```

Comment: Just move your click event handler **below** the code that does the clicking? Better yet control the sorting through whatever actual functions / methods are being used for it rather than faking click events?